# Verify $f(x)=\sin(x)-15$ satisfies the conditions of Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus

The question I have is:

Verify $f(x)=\sin(x)-15$ satisfies the conditions of Rolle's Theorem in the interval $[0,\pi]$ and find a point in the interval $(0,\pi)$ satisfying the theorem.

I know the three conditions of Rolle's theorem, and can prove that $f(a)=f(b)$, however, I am not sure how to prove:

1. $ f(x)$ is differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$
2. $f(x)$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$

Would I use epsilon-delta to prove these two conditions?

Comment: I hope you have seen than the sine function is differentiable everywhere

Comment: Answered analytically down below, make sure to approve the answer if it's the one that fits you so that the thread of the question goes down as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x) = \sin(x) - 15$

The function $\sin(x)$ is a differentiable function and $-15$ is differentiable as a constant. So, $f(x) = \sin(x) - 15$ is differentiable in $(0,\pi)$. It is also continuous as a sum of continuous functions, in $[0,\pi]$.

After that, $f(0)=f(\pi)=-15$.

So, the function $f(x)$ satisfies the conditions of Rolle's Theorem in the interval $[0,\pi]$.

Now, $f'(x) = \cos(x)$. And $f'(x) = 0$ for $x= \frac{\pi}{2} \in [0,\pi]$.

Comment: This is a nice explanation of the problem.  You can produce $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, and $\cot x$ by typing, respectively, \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, and \cot x when you are in math mode.

Comment: Oh thanks for the LaTeX tip !